# React Native | Passing a prop value to setState

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React Native and am interested to start making a Calculator App. But I have a problem.

I created a new component, NumberButton

```
class NumberButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonBox} onPress={this.props.onPress}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.label}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Which takes 'label' as a prop. Then I would like the value of the label to be used in setState, in App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      outputValue: 0,
    }
  }

  changeValue = () => {
    this.setState({
      outputValue: 9,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <OutputBox output={this.state.outputValue}/>
        <View style={styles.buttonRow}>
          <NumberButton onPress={this.changeValue} label="9"/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

So instead of hardcoding setState: 9 everytime, I would it to be like:

*setState: (value of label prop)*

But I really don't know how to do that, so any help on doing it is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a second function in your `NumberButton` component and run the passed function with the parameter you want. You need to be careful about not loosing context of `this` so you need to use either [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or you need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) your function.

**Example**

```
class NumberButton extends React.Component {
  _onPress = () => {
    this.props.onPress(this.props.label)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonBox} onPress={this._onPress}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.label}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

// OR

class NumberButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this._onPress = this._onPress.bind(this)
  }
  _onPress() {
    this.props.onPress(this.props.label)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonBox} onPress={this._onPress}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.label}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

And and then you can use `changeValue` function as follows

```
changeValue = (label) => {
  this.setState({
    outputValue: label,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @bennygenel! The code worked, and thanks for the suggestion, I will study more on that! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply to this...

```
     changeValue(value) {
            this.setState({
            outputValue: value,
            });
          }
```

Pass the function as a prop like this:

```
        <NumberButton onPress={this.changeValue.bind(this)} label={'SetAValue'}/>
```

Then on your Number Component You can trigger the function like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonBox} onPress={this.props.onPress.bind(this,this.props.label)}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.label}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Your Function should take in a parameter for the setState to be dynamic and that would be the value passed from the NumberButton Component :)

Comment: Hey @xSkrappy, your code worked when I tested it too, both yours and the answer above this worked, thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make changeValue method parameterized. So code is -

```
 changeValue = (a) => {
    this.setState({
      outputValue: a,
    });
  }
```

And calling will be like -

```
 <NumberButton onPress={this.changeValue(9)} label="9"/>
```

Comment: Hey, thank for the help, but it still didn't work, it outputs an error of this kind - Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. Thanks for the help though :)